# Is there a simple equivalent of :g/PATTERN/m0 that doesn't reverse the matched lines?

Tags: vim

Occasionally I want to move all lines in a file to the top of that file. `:g/PATTERN/m0` almost does what I want, but because `:g` operates one line at a time in order, it will also reverse the affected lines.

---

Example:

Consider this file. Say I want to separate lines containing a number and move them to the top of the file. `:g/\d/m0` does almost what I want (fr4nk, car0l and b0b are moved to the top) -- but it reverses the order of the matched lines.

```
alice
b0b
car0l
dan
eve
fr4nk
```

Actual output:

```
fr4nk
car0l
b0b
alice
dan
eve
```

Desired output:

```
b0b
car0l
fr4nk
alice
dan
eve
```

---

One way of doing what I want is to use `:g/PATTERN/m$` (which won't reverse lines) and then move the lines from the bottom of the file to the top. Is there anything simpler?

Comment: Oops. Thanks @AlexisWilke!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of moving matching lines to the top <sub>(reverses it)</sub>, move none matching lines to the bottom

```
:v/\d/m$
```

Comment: Now it seems obvious :) Fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

It's not as easy as I would like it to be, but you can do something like this:

```
:let @a='' | exe 'g/\d/d A' | 0put a
```

The breakdown is that it clears register `a`, executes a delete of all matching lines into register `a` (uppercase appends to the register instead of replacing it), then puts the contents of register `a` before the first line of the file.